# What is the difference between chkdsk /f and chkdsk /r?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

> `/F              Fixes errors on the disk.`
>     `/R              Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information (implies /F).`

(from `dir /?`)

It just sounds like the same thing to me.  I never know which one to use - is there even a difference?  Or is it maybe for backwards compatibility with previous versions of Windows where there was a difference?

Comment: Using "/F" only takes minutes and using "/R" takes hours ;)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`chkdsk /r` does the same thing as `chkdsk /f` only it also checks for bad sectors on the disk and recovers any readable information. Running `chkdsk /r` implies that also `chkdsk /f` is run.

`chkdsk /f` only checks for disk errors, not bad sectors.

Microsoft has a detailed page for [chkdsk](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chkdsk.mspx?mfr=true). The following is a snippet explaining /f and /r parameters.

> **Fixing disk errors:**
>
> Chkdsk corrects disk errors only if you specify the /f command-line
>   option. Chkdsk must be able to lock the drive to correct errors.
>   Because repairs usually change a disk's **file allocation table** and
>   sometimes cause a loss of data, chkdsk sends a confirmation message.
>
> **Finding physical disk errors:**
>
> Use the /r command-line option to find **physical disk errors** in the
>   file system.

Comment: I have to be honest, I really didn't know that.  So /r does a "physical" check on top of what's normally checked by /f.  Clear as day now, thanks.

Comment: @kez: Exactly. You're welcome.

Comment: Do not run a `chkdsk /r` unless you think your drive has physically bad sectors (e.g. Event Viewer > System... tells you). Checking a 1 terabyte hard drive could take a day depending on your drive performance.