# I have constant 30-40 second lags on almost every program. The (Not Responding) notice almost always appears

Tags: memory, windows-8.1

I have constant 30-40 second lags on almost every program.

It appears to me to be Windows-8 causing the problem. I'm running

- Windows-8.1 Pro laptop
- Asus i5-3317U 1.7GHz
- 4GB Ram.

This has been a problem since I purchased the laptop.

It always recovers eventually but it is a constant problem with almost every program change that I make.

I'm not doing any gaming or any major loads that I am aware of.

Any clues please?

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit better? Do the lags occur on launch? While using the program? When changing programs? Does the screen update during the lag?

Comment: Usually when changing programs or for instance, beginning a new email or opening a new webpage. Almost without fail there is a 15-od second  lag, then message at top of window (Not Responding) then maybe 15-20 secs more lag then it kicks in. Often get Window in at side advising High Memory usage as well

Comment: I should probably add that I have Norton 360 running as well, if that is relevant.

Comment: Does the same issue occur in safe mode? If the machine is new, take it back!

Comment: `I have Norton 360 running`. Yeah. That's relevant. Actually, all software you're running could be relevant but you can first try [disabling Norton 360](http://www.ehow.com/how_5821205_turn-off-norton-360.html) temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

This may be  a pest to diagnose.

Load it up in safe mode. If this works, then you know the machine is fine, it's either a driver or software.

If SafeMode works/helps, then open the machine normally, type in MSCONFIG and (if you know what you're doing) remove unwanted start up items.

Run a [SMART tool](free smart tool), this will help indiciate if your hard drive life is OK. 
Run [`chkdisk /r`](https://superuser.com/questions/315878/what-is-the-difference-between-chkdsk-f-and-chkdsk-r) at the command prompt and restart the machine (it can take a long time)

Make sure your RAM is all seated correctly.

Take all but 1 RAM chips out and test if the issue persists.

Ensure the [CPU isn't overheating too](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=free+cpu+temp+moniotor#q=free+cpu+temp+monitor&spell=1)

Comment: I have a really strong feeling this is a hard drive issue. I experienced similar problems on two of my computers. I suggest using hddlife to check S.M.A.R.T data and ultimately you can try cloning your drive to another one if possible and see if that helps.